# IPV4 getting removed after restart CentOS machines

Tags: centos, networking, networkmanager, ipv6, ipv4

I have CentOS machines (both 6.x and 7.1) and whenever I reboot them, automatically IPV6 is assigned to them and IPV4 is lost.

Any idea why it is happening and how to prevent it?

I Could not get any info on this issue.
I have access to terminal only, but not the GUI.

Comment: How do you assign IPv4 that gets lost?

Comment: I would be better if you can show us your current `eth0` config file.

Answer (score 0):

download dhcpd and configure in the machine. Then try to assign static IP address.

Download dhcp using yum command in terminal.
To configure - https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-dhcp-configuring-client.html